# Cordova 2.1 error on iOS6 : 4709: CFNetwork internal error

Tags: cordova, ios6

I upgrated Cordova/Phonegap to 2.1 and xCode to version 4.5 (4G182) and now my app can't load some ajax requests through jQuery Mobile 1.2.0-rc.1.

I get in my logs when I build on an iOS 6 device (iPhone 4) or on Simulator 6.0:

```
2012-10-04 10:22:19.760 MyApp[4709:907] Multi-tasking -> Device: YES, App: YES
2012-10-04 10:22:21.994 MyApp[4709:1703] 4709: CFNetwork internal error (0xc01a:/SourceCache/CFNetwork/CFNetwork-609/Connection/URLConnectionClient.cpp:2341)
2012-10-04 10:22:22.217 MyApp[4709:3807] 4709: CFNetwork internal error (0xc01a:/SourceCache/CFNetwork/CFNetwork-609/Connection/URLConnectionClient.cpp:2341)
```

I removed all armv6 references according to [this mail topic](http://osdir.com/ml/phonegap/2012-09/msg01244.html).

I got no problem running on Simulator 5.1.

Thanks in advance for the suggestions!